# Как задать ссылку?

Tags: html, ссылки

Как задать ссылку?
Есть такой код.

```
<div class="container">         
    <div class="gamma-container gamma-loading" id="gamma-container">
        <ul class="gamma-gallery">
            <li>
                <div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Sky high</h3>"
                     data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350">
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div>
                    <div data-src="images/large/3.jpg"></div>
                    <noscript>
                        <img src="images/xsmall/3.jpg" alt="img03"/>
                    </noscript>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Это с плагина адаптивной галереи.
Он выводит одно изображения.
Где именно нужно поставить ссылку чтобы при клике на изображение открывалась страница какая-то.
Пробую разные варианты ничего не работает.

Comment: а вы что, наивно полагаете, что все можно сделать на одном html? Тут вам JavaScript нужен

Comment: Как сделать  через JavaScript?

Comment: для этого надо иметь хотя бы базовые познания в этом языке, да и в программировании вообще

Comment: что за варианты?

Answer (score 1):

В опциях плагина такой возможности нет, однако я нашёл вопрос в котором даётся рекомендация как это сделать. Сам не проверял.
[masonry-question-make-click-a-url-instead-of-larger-gallery-image](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/masonry-question-make-click-a-url-instead-of-larger-gallery-image)